# How to link data from another table to the current table [Android]

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite

I need get data from a table. Then I need to merge the existing data with another data which is from the 2nd table and show it as an output.

ImageSecondPage.java

```
package main.page;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImagesSecondpage extends Activity
{
     ImageAdapter imgDB = new ImageAdapter(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_secondpage);

        imgDB.open();
        Cursor c = imgDB.getAllImages();
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
            DisplayImages(c);

            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
        imgDB.close();

    }

    public void DisplayImages(Cursor c)
    {
        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier("main.page:drawable/pic1", null, null);
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imgView.setImageResource(imageId);
    }

}
```

For now, I only managed to show the image out in the activity. But the requirement is that I must show out the image together with the name of the person which is stored in another table. Now I am stuck at getting the name to display as I don't know how to get the name from another table of the database. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to use raw query: `rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);` or you can `query(...)` to get `cursor` of each table, then compare it with each other. I think the first way is much shorter, but the second way is easier!

**Edit**: For sample code of the second way, you can visit this man's tutorial [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#overview_sqlite), with the first way, you have to know study more about `SQL` statement: [W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp). Hope this help!

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering the question but do you think you can provide me with some sample codes? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest with be to have two Cursor and Join both using [CursorJoiner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorJoiner.html)

```
CursorJoiner joiner = new CursorJoiner(cursorA, keyColumnsofA, cursorB, keyColumnsofB);
 for (CursorJointer.Result joinerResult : joiner) {
     switch (joinerResult) {
         case LEFT:
             // handle case where a row in cursorA is unique
             break;
         case RIGHT:
             // handle case where a row in cursorB is unique
             break;
         case BOTH:
             // handle case where a row with the same key is in both cursors
             break;
     }
 }
```

Another option will be to use the [SQLiteQueryBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html) and use [setTables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#setTables%28java.lang.String%29) then suing query() method to get your Cursor.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question. The cursors are the tables that I wanted to link together? Am I right to say that?